Kafka SQL Server Windows Authentication
In a sense this is a follow up question to my previous one: SQL Server with DB Visualizer
So as suggested by the user @AlwaysLearning, if one tries to use Windows Authentication, then jTDS driver is the way to go.
Now I am using Kafka connect with SQL Server, the panic thing is about the configuration, as the following shown.

For the connnection.url, I use jTDS. However, as it is about Windows Authentication, I did not enter "connection.user": "..." and "connection.password": "..." as it usually does. But then I ended up with error that

java.io.IOException: GSS Failed: Invalid name provided (Mechanism level: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm).

How do I overcome this difficulty?
After some struggling to look for solutions around, I feel like the issue is about working Windows Authentication with Docker. At least my Kafka Connect is hosted in Docker. But I really have no idea how to solve this issue.

I would suggest forgetting about jtds driver and use the official one. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-ntlm-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16 or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-kerberos-integrated-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16 can be used for linux windows auth, i'd go with the ntlm domain one, if you want to save yourself the hassle

@siggemannen, actually I have tried the Microsoft jdbc before, it would always end up with connection refused problem. Actually this was the very first thing that I tried in my previous post.

Well, since it's working for everyone else, then i assume you're doing something wrong :) Note that docker environment's localhost/127... points inside docker usually, not to your host machine's localhost. You need to use specific host.docker.internal path

For a start you are going to need to use the FQDN not the IP address. You also need to specify Integrated Security. So you need something like jdbc:sqlserver://YourServer.YourDomain.com:1433;integratedSecurity=true
